# How to define a quaternion group of order 8

Tags: group-theory, quaternions

I'm having problems to understand the way the quaternion group $Q_8$ is represented.

I have seen definitions using the elements $i,j$ and $k$, but these same letters don't appear in another definition where each element is represented as a matrix, where only $1$ and $i$ are used.

How can I relate these different representations?

Comment: Describing the subgroups of $Q_8$ and relating two descriptions of $Q_8$ are two different questions. I don't think doing the latter has anything to do with doing the former. As for how to do the former: there are only eight elements, it shouldn't be hard to see that any two nontrivial elements generate the group, so you can do this by hand. And doing the latter: can you figure out which matrices to make $i,j,k$? Can you prove they satisfy the same relations as them (equivalently, have the same multiplication table)?

Comment: The quaternion group has 2 generators $a$ and $b$, satisfying $a^4=1$, $b^2=a^2$, and $ba=a^{-1}b$. From that, you can decide whether any given group presentation is, in fact, the quaternion gorup, and you can find all the subgroups.

Comment: I simplified the question by removing the mentions of subgroups. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are in the happy position of working with a group of small order, I think you would be well served by writing out the elements of the group, and the product of each pair of elements (including things like a$^2$, and also remembering that ab need not = ba).  Organize this information in any way that makes sense to you (maybe a chart?).  Then pick whatever description of the group fits well with how you organized things. Once you have wrapped your brain around the specifics of the group, you will probably understand all the representations.

Comment: @anon, I can't figure out which matrices to use for i, j, k. That is precisely the problem. My problem is to understand why in one definition one element is {(-i, 0), (0, i)} and not, say, {(i, 0), (0, i)}.

Comment: @betty, how do I decide how to represent the elements of the group? What are they?

Comment: This is (essentially) a problem in Herstein, which ask you to see whether there exist any non-abelian group where all subgroup are normal; this group is the smallest. I actually have to construct the group by hand, and it's quite time consuming. But it's not as bad as you think it is, because it's quite symmetric. Out of 8 element, only 2 are special: the identity and the involution. Pick any 3 element in one group from the 6 so that none of them is a power of another, and do the same to another group in other definition, and you can always find an isomorphism that map that 3 into that 3.

Comment: @nightcoder Gerry Myerson has listed the 8 elements in his representation #2.  What I would suggest however is that you create an 8x8 multiplication table for this group based on the conditions Gerry has given.  Then maybe make up a separate column of each element and its inverse. Once you've gotten that far, you need to replace each element of the 8 Gerry listed with a 2x2 matrix.  You choose them so that they have the same multiplicative properties as the original elements.  You can do this by inspection.

Answer (score 11):

Here are two ways to tell people about the quaternion group:

1. $\{\,1,i,j,k,-1,-i,-j,-k\,\}$ with $ij=k$, $jk=i$, $ki=j$, $ji=-k$, $kj=-i$, $ik=-j$, $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$.
2. $\{\,1,a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b,a^3b\,\}$ with $a^4=1$, $b^2=a^2$, $ba=a^3b$.

You can see they describe the same group by, for example, using the relations in the first description to show that the elements can also be given as 
$\{\,1,i,i^2,i^3,j,ij,i^2j,i^3j\,\}$ with $i^4=1$, $j^2=i^2$, and $ji=i^3j$.

Now your challenge is to do the same thing with a way of listing the elements as 2-by-2 matrices.

As for the question of why use this matrix and not that matrix, my advice is to try both ways and see what happens (and feel free to report back here on your findings).