# Quaternion group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions

Let $S = \{ i, j, k\}$, $G =  \langle S  \rangle$. And  $i\cdot j = k $,    $j\cdot k = i, k\cdot i = j, i^2=j^2=k^2$.
I have to show that $G = \{e, i, j, k, i^2, i^2\cdot i, i^2\cdot j, i^2\cdot k \}$.

So my plan is to show that every arbitrary element from $G$ can be expressed in one of the following forms:$(i^2)^m, (i^2)^m\cdot i, (i^2)^m\cdot j,(i^2)^m\cdot k$, where $m$ is non-negative integer. And then i can prove $(i^2)^2 = e$. Unfortunately, i don't know what to start with, because there are a lot of representations of my arbitraty element.

And in general case, if i know some generating set $\langle S  \rangle$, how can i find $G$?

Comment: Just write out all elements you can form with $S$. At some point they are no new ones. Here with $Q_8$ this happens quite quickly. Then google "generating sets of quaternion group", to see if you were right (see the answer in this [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628671/how-to-define-a-quaternion-group-of-order-8)).

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok, i will try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the multiplication table of the group. You can do that graphically, too, by constructing the Cayley graph. Like this one:

[image: Cayley graph of the quaternion group]

The red arrow corresponds to the multiplication by $i$, the green arrow to the multiplication by $j$.

[Edit: expanded table creation]

Start with the set $\{1\}$. Obviuosly, if you try to create the multiplication table, you obtain something like this:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|}
\hline
\cdot & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Now you would like to add $-1$. This is what you get:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
\hline
\cdot & 1 & -1\\ \hline
1 & 1 & -1\\ \hline
-1 & -1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Now, if you try to add $i$:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\cdot & 1 & -1 & i\\ \hline
1 & 1 & -1 & i\\ \hline
-1 & -1 & 1 & -i\\ \hline
i & i & -i & -1\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

you realize that this table is not complete, as it contains a new element: $-i$. So you have to add also $-i$ to your set:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\cdot & 1 & -1 & i & -i\\ \hline
1 & 1 & -1 & i & -i\\ \hline
-1 & -1 & 1 & -i & i\\ \hline
i & i & -i & -1 & 1\\ \hline
-i & -i & i & 1 & -1\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

and now the table is complete.

Now it's time to add $j$, but as you start creating the table, you realize that you have to add also $-j$ (because $-1\cdot j=-j$), $k$ (because it's equal to $i\cdot j$) and $-k$. Now the set $\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ is closed.

Comment: This is a nice picture (+1). OK, it is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group), but still...

Comment: When i should stop, when i'm forming a multiplication table of a group?

Comment: When the table is complete. Try constructing it, inserting one element at a time. If you use only 1, then you obtain a trivial $1\times1$ table (the trivial subgroup). When you add $i$, you obtain a $4\times4$ table (the group $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ Then you can add $j$...

Comment: @DietrichBurde, should I make a link to Wikipedia? Or a note?

Comment: @zar So in general case, if i have 3 elements, then my table is $3\times 3$, if 4, then it's $4\times 4$ and so on?

Comment: No, there is no such "general case" . It depends on the multiplication table of the elements.

Comment: @zar And when i'm done with table, i can make a conclusion that every multipliaction is either $i$, $j$ or $k$ or $-i$, $-j$, $-k$?

Comment: @FalsePromise, don't forget $+1$ and $-1$